# How do I remove indention with XDocument.Load

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have a simple XML-file with only one line in it:

```
<Foo><Bar>foobar</Bar></Foo>
```

I use XDocument to load the content in a console application, like so:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(pathToXmlFile)
```

If I use `Console.WriteLine` to output the `xDoc`variable I get an indented version of the line:

```
<Foo>
    <Bar>foobar</Bar>
</Foo>
```

It also looks indented when inspecting the variable at runtime. My question is how I can get rid of the indention when loading the XML so that it still only occupies one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    Dim xe As XElement = <root><el></el></root>
    Dim s As String = xe.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)
    Debug.WriteLine(s)
```

outputs

```
<root><el></el></root>
```

Without SaveOptions.DisableFormatting the output is

```
<root>
  <el></el>
</root>
```